# How can I add a headrest to this office chair?

Tags: comfort

I must have headrest added to this chair.  The attachable type that can be purchased online would not work on this type of chair.  Any help is appreciated.  I need it to look nice for office environment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your office chair (brand) manufacturer has that model available with and without a headrest, there's an excellent chance you could purchase the accessory and retrofit it to your chair.
OR
You could purchase something similar to this.
 [image: Lorel high-back chair headrest]
 It's a [Lorel high-back chair headrest](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00P85C6OU) and attach it to the back of your chair with screws. It's a mesh design but doesn't look too too-bad (opinion).

Two illustrated methods with step-by-step instructions for making and adding a headrest can be found [here](https://toergonomics.com/how-to-add-a-headrest-to-an-office-chair/); but, functionality is stressed over appearance.

Good luck.